# Class.innerClass or classInstance.innerClass?

Tags: java

I am wondering how come I can reach inner class directly from outer type as if it is a static member like :

```
public class Hello {
    public class UnderHello
    {
        void runObject()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

So when I reach the `UnderHello`

```
public class SomeOtherClass {
    public void ClickOnMe()
    {
            Hello.UnderHello //this is shown by auto-complete
    }
}
```

I was expecting something like this :

```
public class SomeOtherClass {
    public void ClickOnMe()
    {
            Hello world = new Hello();
            world.UnderHello // after creating an instance, then UnderHello should now be seen by auto-complete
    }
}
```

If `UnderHello` was a `static` class, it would make sense since I can reach static members of a class by directly from Class itself rather than creating instance of the outer class. But it is inner-class.

I am confused.

Can somebody help me now?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you can do `Hello.UnderHello`?

Comment: @The Elite : Yeah but I am not talking about creating an instance of that type but just reaching it with auto-complete/intellisense.

Comment: I've added my answer to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Hello.UnderHello` is correct, because that is the name of the class.

This does not mean, however, that you can actually create instances of this inner class without an instance of the outer class.

```
 Hello.UnderHello x = new Hello.UnderHello(); // this will not work 
                   // at least not from everywhere
```

> If UnderHello was a static class, it would make sense since I can reach static members of a class by directly from Class itself rather than creating instance of the outer class.

The class definition itself is always static, if you will. You do not need an instance to refer to it (and the class definition also does not change with the outer instance).

If `UnderHello` was a field or a method, then yes, you would need an instance to access it, unless it was declared `static`.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer but I didn't quite understand this part : "The class definition itself is always static, if you will. You do not need an instance to refer to it (and the class definition also does not change with the outer instance)."

Comment: Well, the type `Hello.UnderHello` is just a (more or less) regular class. All instances of it use the same class file. For all of them `x instanceof Hello.UnderHello` is true and `x.getClass()` will return the same object.

Answer (score 3):

The syntax is this:

```
new Hello().new UnderHello();
```

And since this is awfully confusing, I think it shouldn't be used. Non-static inner classes should be private (or better: package-scoped) and should be instantiated from the outer class only.

Comment: why better package-scoped? My answer is that making them private adds unnecessary overhead in the form of wrapper methods. Better to make the class package-scoped, which it sort of is anyway under the hoods.

Comment: exactly: because of the automatically generated wrapper methods

Answer (score 1):

You can type Hello.UnderHello because it's the name of the type, but you can't for instance initialize it using `new Hello.UnderHello()`, you need

```
Hello hello = new Hello();
hello.new UnderHello();
```

Answer (score 1):

i think ,because UnderHello is a **nested class** with in the Hello Class Scope so there is no other way to reach to this class except through parent class.

Its like Namespace.ClassName

Answer (score 0):

Since `UnderHello` isn't a static inner class, you can only instantiate it like this:

```
new Hello().new UnderHello();
```

But it's type is `Hello.UnderHello`.